# Animation of a point in a 3D plot

Tags: matlab, animation

I need to create an animation of moving point without plotting actual trajectory. So I can't use `comet3` or I don't understand how to use it in that way. I've found [animatedline](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/animatedline.html) function which has properties that I need but I don't have this function in my Matlab 2014.

Could you give me any advice how to solve this problem?

Comment: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/animatedline-object.html

Comment: I've written that I don't have animatedline.

Comment: You can use `set(h,'XData',...,'YData',...);` with  `h` being the line handle to the actual point. If you have problems using this approach, please tell.

Comment: For animating a single point, this [question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22596910/animation-process-in-matlab) should get you started.